# execute a function (ref cursor) in a jsp using jdbc and show the resultset

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I am having a database function which its name is `get_budget(year_v, usr_v)` and accepting two parameters the `year` and the `usr`. Now, I am trying to execute this by using the jdbc.

In toad when I am trying to execute using a select statement : `select get_budget(2010, maa_maa) from dual`, it is diaplaying a cursor. But how do that in the jdbc, so I can retrieve the data directly and print them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is about the same as in dynamic sql, describe the cursor, find the columns and datatypes and print the accordingly. See for example [Selecting the ref_cursor from JDBC](http://www.oradev.com/ref_cursor.jsp)